# Pass variable name to a function in r

Tags: function, r, variables

Is it possible to pass just a variable name in a function call and have it utilised as such within the function??

pseudocode:

```
q<-function(A){
    b<-(w%in%A.2|w%in%A.7)  
    factor(b,levels=c(F,T),labels=c("non-"A,A))}


w<-c(0:10)
e.2<-c(1,2)
e.7<-c(6,7)
```

what I´d like to do is

```
q(e)
```

and have returned

non-e,e,e,non-e,non-e,e,e,non-e,non-e

//M

---

```
q<-function(A) {
    a2<-get(paste(a,".2",sep=""))
    a7<-get(paste(a,".7",sep=""))
    b<-(w%in%a2|%in%a7) 
    factor(b,levels=c(F,T),labels=c(paste("non-",a,sep=""),a)) 
}

q("e")
```

Thx,

M

Comment: In fourth line should be `b<-(w%in%a2|w%in%a7)` or `b<-w%in%c(a2,a7)`. And you use `A` as argument and `a` in code.

Comment: This question could be cleaned up. The example code is much too specific to one user’s needs and includes too much irrelevant noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get`

For instance

```
var1 <- get(paste(e, ".2", sep=""))
var2 <- get(paste(e, ".7", sep=""))
```

EDIT: as Aidan Cully correctly says then you should call your function as `q("e")` (i.e. with a string)

Comment: Note also that the OP should call `q("e")` instead of `q(e)`.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably choose a different name for your function other than "q" - otherwise you'll never be able to finish ;)