# how to Reading Csv file and calculating mean in R dynamically?

Tags: r, csv

I want to read a file and calculate the mean of it.

```
`>list
[1] "book1.csv" "book2.csv".
```

for book1

```
observation1
    23
    24
    65
    76
    34
```

In books i  have a variable observation 1 and observation 2 column for book 1 and 2 respectively.  So i want to write a function where i can calculate mean of it.I am new to R and not able subset the variable of books. Can anyone please help me out in writing the function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  File represents the file to be read in (book1) and the variable represents the variable to take mean over (observation 1)

```
read.mean<-function(file,variable){
  df<-read.csv(file)
  mean.df <- mean(df[,variable])
  return(mean.df)
}
```

Make sure to pass your arguments in quotes, i.e. `read.mean("book1", "observation1")`.  There is a way to do it without the quotes ([Passing a variable name to a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133980/passing-a-variable-name-to-a-function-in-r)) but it is complicated.