# entering variable name as argument of a function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm trying to make a function that will run and compare a set of models given a dataset and a variable name (essentially to be able to change just one model set and have them apply to all relevant dependent variables--selecting an a priori modelset to compare rather than using a data-dredging existing function like glmulti). A simple example:

```
RunModelset<- function(dataset, response)
{
  m1 <- lm(formula=response ~ 1, data=dataset) 
  m2 <- lm(formula=response ~ 1 + temperature, data=dataset)
  comp <- AICctab(m1,m2, base = T, weights = T, nobs=length(data))
  return(comp)
}
```

If I manually enter a specific variable name within the function, it runs the models correctly. However, using the code above and entering a text value for the response argument doesn't work:

```
RunModel(dataset=MyData,response="responsevariablename")
```

yields an error: invalid type (NULL) for variable 'dataset$response', which I interpret to mean it isn't finding the column I'm telling it to use. My problem must be in how R inserts a text value as an argument in the function.

How do I enter the response variable name so R knows that "formula=response ~" becomes "formula=dataset$responsevariablename ~"?

**ETA Working answer** based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133980/passing-a-variable-name-to-a-function-in-r/19134129#19134129):

```
RunModel<- function(dataset, response)
{
 resvar <- eval(substitute(response),dataset)
 m1 <- lm(formula=resvar ~ 1, data=dataset) 
 m2 <- lm(formula=resvar ~ 1 + R.biomass, data=dataset)
 comp <- AICctab(m1,m2, base = T, weights = T, nobs=length(data))
 return(comp)
}

RunModel(dataset=MyData,response=responsevariablename)
```

NB - this didn't work when I had quotes on the response argument.

Comment: try `RunModel(dataset=MyData,response=as.name("responsevariablename")) `

Comment: maybe use `formula(paste0(text, "~", variable, "+", variable2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use match.call() to achieve this.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19134129/6041964)

Comment: I couldn't get match.call to work, but the eval(substitute()) [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133980/passing-a-variable-name-to-a-function-in-r/19134129#19134129) posted on that question does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Should I edit Keqiang's answer, provide one of my own or just paste my solution into a comment here?