# how to use a character string to serve as a subset index of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a function like this:

```
func <- function(abc){
   idnumber <- data$abc
}
```

in which users can input the `abc` (a character string), and I want to get the column of that string. For example, if user inputs `student`, I want to get `idnumber <- data$student` but not `data$student`. Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: There are two ways to do this.  One you pass the variable as a string and utilize Psidom suggestions.  Two you don't pass the variable as a string.  To do this read this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133980/passing-a-variable-name-to-a-function-in-r/34079727#34079727.  I believe that my answers is the superior approach.

Comment: data[[abc]] is also a possibility, as it also works for lists

Comment: Not clear. What do you actually want? A variable in the global environment by the name idnumber and "func" wou ld have what value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Data[ abc_val]
```

Or

```
Data[[ abc_val]]
```

Where abc_val is a character value perhaps equal to "abc". Really should pass a value to "Data", though.