# Columns `x`, `y` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm building a ggplot wrapper function to use for multiple plots. Now I get this error which I don't understand.

This is my function:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_hist_trend <- function(df, title, subtitle = "", x_axis, y_axis, point_color) {
  df %>%
   ggplot(aes(x_axis, y_axis)) +
    geom_smooth(color = "black") +
    geom_point(color = point_color) +
    theme(legend.position = "right") +
    labs(title = title,
         subtitle = subtitle,
         x = "",
         y = "",
         caption = "Data: NOAA")
}
```

This is a subset of my dataframe.

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2018L, 2017L, 2016L, 2015L, 2014L), n = c(52L, 
53L, 47L, 47L, 55L)), .Names = c("year", "n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

...but when I plot my ggplot2 object I run into this `1d atomic vector or list` error.

```
plot_hist_trend(df, title = "Title",
                  x_axis = year, y_axis = n,
                  point_color = "#D0021B")
```

Tnx in advance!

Comment: It takes special work to pass unquoted column names to a function. See, e.g., [Programming with ggplot](https://rpubs.com/hadley/97970), especially the "Indirectly Referencing Variables" section. Also see the [Programming with dplyr Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

Comment: There's probably a better canonical dupe out there, but here's one possible duplicate: [Pass column names to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40898596/903061). [Pass character column names to ggplot within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19826352/903061) is a bit dated because it only mentions the `aes_string` approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Gregor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code ! It works for me

```
plot_hist_trend(df, title = "Title",
            x_axis =df$year, y_axis = df$n,
            point_color = "#D0021B")
```

[image]

Comment: This does work in this case but is bad practice. It essentially ignores the `df` argument, and would probably break with more complicated plots (e.g., if a `stat` function or facets were used).

Answer (score 1):

You may choose to use `rlang::enexpr` or `base::substitute` to solve this problem like below and then use `aes_q` from `ggplot`

```
plot_hist_trend <- function(df, title, subtitle = "", x_axis, y_axis, point_color) {
    x_axis <- rlang::enexpr(x_axis)
    y_axis <- rlang::enexpr(y_axis)
    df %>%
        ggplot(aes_q(x_axis, y_axis)) +
        geom_smooth(color = "black") +
        geom_point(color = point_color) +
        theme(legend.position = "right") +
        labs(title = title,
             subtitle = subtitle,
             x = "",
             y = "",
             caption = "Data: NOAA")
}
```

I hope this works for you, please notify in case of otherwise.