# R - Passing a column name to a function to be evaluated in a non standard way

Tags: r

I have a data-frame where I want to pass a column name to R in and then filter based on that column.
I have tried reading a few tutorials on this and it seems to be related to non standard evaluation in R.

I cant seem to wrap my head around the examples in the blog posts I have read.
Just for simplicity, I have taken the iris dataset and I want to pass a column to a function which will then filter that dataset where the column value is greater than one.

```
mydf <- iris

filter_measurements <- function(mydf, measurement){

  mydf <- filter(measurement >= 1)
  mydf

}

mydf %>% 
  filter_measurements(measurement = Petal.Width)
```

Do I have to add something to my function so that R knows I want a column and not use it as 'Petal.Width' for example.

I have seen [Passing a variable name to a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133980/passing-a-variable-name-to-a-function-in-r) which i was unable to adapt to my example

Thank you all for your time

Comment: The problem with your example is that dplyr::filter itself uses non-standard evaluation.

Comment: `deparse(substitute())` could help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great resource for this is [Programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

```
mydf <- iris

filter_measurements <- function(mydf, measurement){
  measurement <- enquo(measurement)

  mydf <- filter(mydf, (!!measurement) >= 1)
  mydf

}

mydf %>% 
  filter_measurements(measurement = Petal.Width)
```

You have to tell the function that measurement is giving as a bare variable name. For this first use `enquo` to evaluate what is given in the measurement argument and store it as a quosure. Then with `!!` in front of measurement the `filter` function knows that it doesn't have to quote this argument, as it is already a quosure.

**Alternative**

You can also pass the column you want to filter on as a string and use `filter_`:

```
filter_measurements <- function(mydf, measurement){

  mydf <- filter_(mydf, paste0(measurement, " >= 1"))
  mydf

}

mydf %>% 
  filter_measurements(measurement = "Petal.Width")
```

Comment: Hi @kath, thank you so much for this very concise answer. It makes much more sense now. Have a nice weekend

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the column name either as character or integer index of the column. Also, the line

```
mydf <- filter(measurement >= 1)
```

within your function never states *what* is being filtered and will expect the "measurement" to be a stand-alone object, not a part of a data frame.
Try this:

```
filter_measurements <- function(mydf, measurement)
{
  mydf <- filter(mydf, mydf[,measurement] >= 1)
  mydf
}

iris %>% filter_measurements("Petal.Width")
```

A more convoluted invocation of the function would also work:

```
iris %>% filter_measurements(which(names(.)=="Petal.Width"))
```